# Error - #1046 - Base de datos no seleccionada

Tags: mysql, wordpress, cpanel

Estoy intentando subir una base de datos de un **BackUp** que hice de una pagina, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error
consulta SQL:


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

```
1046 - Base de datos no seleccionada
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te hace falta escribir

```
`USE NOMBRE_BASE`
```

Esta instrucción te sirve para seleccionar la base de datos, después agregas tu código y debe de funcionar

Comment: Ok, entonces copio el código `script` mejor y pego ese codigo primero que las tablas?

Comment: use nombre_base e inmediatamente después en una línea nueva, pegas tu código y veras que te funciona

Comment: Pues, lo que hice fue crear la db usando el editor que trae mi hosting y luego en phpmAdmin, solo seleccione la base de datos, adjunte la anterior y todo funciono, gracias